# Want to display data in view through controller

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, variables

> This is my controller

```
public function get_masteradmin_data()
        {
            $this->load->model('AppconfigModel');
            $result= $this->AppconfigModel->get_masteradmin_data();
        echo $result;
        }
```

> This is my Model : I am getting data from database. but , my issue is , when i use echo statement in my model , it display all documents in json format without any error. but , when i want to display all documents by storing data in a variable and pass that variable in my controller function , it does not work. What should i do to store all data in a variable and return that variable in the controller, so that i can use that data (through variable)further . What code should i need to add in my controller and model.

```
$result = $mongo->executeQuery('justrack_db.master_admin', $query);

            foreach($result as $r)
        {

        $res = json_encode($r);


        }
        return $res;
```

> I also tried by returning $res and storing data in controller in a $result variable and echo that variable. but , by doing this , it only print 1 document out of 7

Comment: I think you haven't return $res variable

Comment: I already tried , that , but issue is i have 7 documents in my collection , when i return $res , it shows only 1 document , out of 7. How to fix that

Comment: have you returned inside sloop or outside the loop?

Comment: inside the loop

Comment: you should put it outside the loop.

Comment: check my new edited code above. i am using outside loop , it still giving me only 1 document

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
$result = $mongo->executeQuery('justrack_db.master_admin', $query);
        $res = array();
            foreach($result as $r)
        {

        $res[] = $r;


        }
    return json_encode($res);
```

Comment: you can do this too. $result = array();
$result = $mongo->executeQuery('justrack_db.master_admin', $query);
return json_encode($result ); . Will save you for loop.